# Python request dropping parameter value

Tags: python, python-requests, facebook-ads-api

I am calling Facebook API which requires one of the parameters in this format:
time_range {'since':YYYY-MM-DD,'until':YYYY-MM-DD}

I build my parameters like this:

```
parameters2 = dict(access_token=api_token, level='ad', time_range={'since':'2020-05-10','until':'2020-05-11'})
```

Then call it:

```
response = requests.get(url2, params=parameters2)
```

However, since/until is getting dropped from the request:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://graph.facebook.com:443 "GET /v7.0/xxx/insights?level=ad&lction_attirbution_windows=1d_click&time_range=since&time_range=until HTTP/1.1" 400 140
```

And I get the error back:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) param time_range must be non-empty.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AH8BwpzA5-Gtnpus_FDkrNg"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time_range="{'since' : '2020-05-10','until' : '2020-05-11'}"
```

Did the trick